# Extract attribute value from log file and store logs in separate file based on attribute value

Tags: linux, awk

I am trying to generate different log files for each user based on the pattern. #

As the log files are quite huge (couple of hundred of GBs), I want to use awk or a similar shell command to process it efficiently.

Sample input log looks like:

---

```
2019-09-01T06:04:55+00:00 xxxxxxxx CEF: 0|XXX XXXX XXX|YYY-OS|9.0.3|end|TRAFFIC|1|rt=Sep 12 2019 06:04:55 GMT deviceExternalId=11111000000 dvchost=ABCDEFGHIJ src=0.0.0.0 dst=0.0.0.0 sourceTranslatedAddress=0.0.0.0 destinationTranslatedAddress=0.0.0.0 cs1Label=Rule_name cs1=sec_t2u_allow_ssl suser=intra\\test.user1 duser= app=ssl\n

2019-09-01T06:04:55+00:00 xxxxxxxx CEF: 0|XXX XXXX XXX|YYY-OS|9.0.3|end|TRAFFIC|1|rt=Sep 12 2019 06:04:55 GMT deviceExternalId=11111000000 dvchost=ABCDEFGHIJ src=0.0.0.0 dst=0.0.0.0 sourceTranslatedAddress=0.0.0.0 destinationTranslatedAddress=0.0.0.0 cs1Label=Rule_name cs1=sec_t2u_allow_ssl suser=intra\\ts-test.user2 duser= app=ssl\n

2019-09-01T06:04:55+00:00 xxxxxxxx CEF: 0|XXX XXXX XXX|YYY-OS|9.0.3|end|TRAFFIC|1|rt=Sep 12 2019 06:04:55 GMT deviceExternalId=11111000000 dvchost=ABCDEFGHIJ src=0.0.0.0 dst=0.0.0.0 sourceTranslatedAddress=0.0.0.0 destinationTranslatedAddress=0.0.0.0 cs1Label=Rule_name cs1=sec_t2u_allow_ssl suser= duser= app=ssl\n
```

Some usernames are present but not for all. In case if "suser= " I want to put it in separate file

Expected output format would be:

---

```
###test.user1.log -->###

2019-09-01T06:04:55+00:00 xxxxxxxx CEF: 0|XXX XXXX XXX|YYY-OS|9.0.3|end|TRAFFIC|1|rt=Sep 12 2019 06:04:55 GMT deviceExternalId=11111000000 dvchost=ABCDEFGHIJ src=0.0.0.0 dst=0.0.0.0 sourceTranslatedAddress=0.0.0.0 destinationTranslatedAddress=0.0.0.0 cs1Label=Rule_name cs1=sec_t2u_allow_ssl suser=intra\\\\test.user1 duser= app=ssl\n

.....

###ts-test.user2.log --> ###

2019-09-01T06:04:55+00:00 xxxxxxxx CEF: 0|XXX XXXX XXX|YYY-OS|9.0.3|end|TRAFFIC|1|rt=Sep 12 2019 06:04:55 GMT deviceExternalId=11111000000 dvchost=ABCDEFGHIJ src=0.0.0.0 dst=0.0.0.0 sourceTranslatedAddress=0.0.0.0 destinationTranslatedAddress=0.0.0.0 cs1Label=Rule_name cs1=sec_t2u_allow_ssl suser=intra\\ts-test.user2 duser= app=ssl\n

.....

###others.log --> ###

2019-09-01T06:04:55+00:00 xxxxxxxx CEF: 0|XXX XXXX XXX|YYY-OS|9.0.3|end|TRAFFIC|1|rt=Sep 12 2019 06:04:55 GMT deviceExternalId=11111000000 dvchost=ABCDEFGHIJ src=0.0.0.0 dst=0.0.0.0 sourceTranslatedAddress=0.0.0.0 destinationTranslatedAddress=0.0.0.0 cs1Label=Rule_name cs1=sec_t2u_allow_ssl suser= duser= app=ssl\n
```

I tried to find regex to match the pattern.

This regex **"(\bsuser\b)=(.*?(?=\s\w+=|$))"** could be used to match the pattern similar to **"suser=abcd\\ts-test.user"**

Comment: Prepend the data with 4 spaces or use the `{}` in the editor.

Comment: Just read line by line in `awk`, extract the `suser=(this_part)` and redirect output of the line to `print $0 > "ts-user" this_part ".log"`. And before that check if `this_part` is empty, if it is set it to "others". What do you have problem with? What is your question?

Comment: Yeah that sounds about right. I am new to awk & regex, I tried something like this `awk '/suser=intra\\\\test.user1/' log_file.log`, it can get me all logs for the test.user1, but was not sure how to complete the rest of it. 
I hardcoded for user `intra\\test.user1` in the above condition, it should redirect each users logs to individual log files for ex: `intra\\test.user1.log` file.

Answer (score 0):

Some of the regexp operators that were included in the questio are not available in awk 4.1.4 that I have (for example '(?=)'). So that the regexp needed some modification

Here is a small single-line awk script that you can use as a starting point

```
 awk '
/suser=/ {
    # fallback log file
    logfile = "others.log"
    # Extra user ID to items[1] from $0 '**suser=' token
    if ( match($0, " suser=\\S+\\.(\\w+)", items) ) {
        logfile = items[1] ".log"
    } 
    # print NR, logfile
    print $0 > logfile
}'
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I tried this but it sends all logs to others.log file rather than filtering all different users log. 
Additionally, there was no * actually in the text, I just included it to make it bold. But as it was edited later, it showed up as *.
Also, is there a way to actually test this regex ? I used https://regex101.com, but It doesn't seems to work. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am currently using this regex: `"suser=(\\w*\\S+)"` it works fine, just each output file contains single quotes, for ex: 'intra\\test.user1.log'. Not sure how to fix that. 
Maybe you could update your answer based on my above comment and I could accept it as answer.